# Simple Java Command Not Running in Cron

Tags: java, shell, cron, sh

We are trying unsuccessfully to run a java command in the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -jar /home/cyberren/cyberren/cyberexe/D50_1_Migration.jar > d50Migration.log
```

We call it with the following line in our cron file:

```
45 08 * * * /home/cyberren/queries/d50migration.sh
```

We have confirmed that the shell script runs via cron, but it doesn't execute the java. It tries, but our log output is just this one line:

```
2016-Jun-30 08:58:11 - D50_1_Migration Process v104
```

We expect many more lines following such as this:

```
2016-Jun-30 08:58:11 - D50_1_Migration Process v104
2016-Jun-30 08:58:11 - migrateData -> SQL: UPDATE D50_1 SET xassessment = 192, iStepsTotal = 9 WHERE xIndx = 128
2016-Jun-30 08:58:11 - migrateData -> SQL: UPDATE D50_1 SET xassessment = 192, iStepsTotal = 9 WHERE xIndx = 129
...
```

We are able to run the same shell script manually, and it executes the java. We are also able to execute the java line manually, and it runs correctly.

So to repeat:

- The cron job runs as scheduled
- The shell script runs
- The log is created, but only with the initial line
- The java line in the shell script does not run
- Both the shell script and the standalone java line run manually successfully
- We have confirmed all directories referenced

Thanks in advance for the thoughts and advice.

Updates/Additional Info:

- (Edit) Permissions are correct
- (Edit) Tried adding a preceding `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` line per Alex's advice. Same output.

**Solution:**

- @Jackson, you probably don't have access to the source code for the jar file, so debugging would be fruitless. Try setting up the cron job so that it is called from a bash login and sends STDERR output to STDOUT and logs both in a file, this should do it, `45 08 * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/cyberren/queries; ./d50migration.sh 2&>1 |tee -a /home/cyberren/d50migration.log"` this way you should get to see all output and error output generated (if any) – Finbarr O'Brien 22 mins ago
- At first we were pretty happy to have a way to look at our errors, but your cron line successfully ran the .jar! You've solved our problem and given us a way to successufully schedule and run java archive files via cron.

Comment: Hi ! You can try to add mode debug lines in your jar in order to see where it bugs

Comment: @Jägermeister Permissions are good! We confirmed with the same user via PuTTY.

Comment: @Jérèm Does it make sense that it would bug when run via cron but not when run manually?

Comment: Based on the fact that you get a line in the log, either the java program exits prematurely, or has hung somewhere. Are there any occurrances of the java process if you do `ps -fu cyberren` (assuming your user is 'cyberren')? I would suggest to try step debugging with your favourite IDE through the java code by adding debug parameters to the java command such as: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777` and see where it fails

Comment: Hint: never put more information into comments; update your question instead.

Comment: I've also experienced in the past, the script executed through crontab did not have environment variables set. you could add ". ~/.profile". This, or the current working directory are not the same, cd "$(dirname "$0")" would fix it.

Comment: @Finbarr I can work on debugging, my java is a little beyond rusty, so I want to confirm that the rest of it looks good before I dust off my old java mind. This is a .jar given to us by the developers of our EHR software. I agree that it looks like the java program is ending prematurely. But why could this be the case if it runs ok manually? What's the difference really? Excuse my lack of knowledge, trying to learn as much as I can here while I work on solving this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jägermeister I had also edited my post to include the answer to your question. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, the redirect to d50Migration.log would put the file in the crontab's current directory, so it may be working, but just writing the log file in another directory (I believe that would be your home folder)

Comment: @Alex Tried adding a preceding `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` line, same output. Also we aren't having trouble locating our log file, it's just not being added to past the opening first line.

Comment: @Jackson, you probably don't have access to the source code for the jar file, so debugging would be fruitless. Try setting up the cron job so that it is called from a bash login and sends STDERR output to STDOUT and logs both in a file, this should do it, `45 08 * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/cyberren/queries; ./d50migration.sh 2&>1 |tee -a /home/cyberren/d50migration.log"` this way you should get to see all output and error output generated (if any)

Comment: @Finbarr This actually solved our issue and ran the java successfully! And taught us how to output any errors as well :) I've credited you in an edit of my original question, but if you post it as an answer I'll accept it!

Thanks again

Comment: Much appreciated for the recognition :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting up the cron job so that it is called from a bash login and sends STDERR output to STDOUT and logs both in a file, this should do it:

```
45 08 * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/cyberren/queries; ./d50migration.sh 2>&1 |tee -a /home/cyberren/d50migration.log"
```

this way you should get to see all output and error output generated (if any)

Comment: Thanks again! Made an aggravating Friday into a nice start to the holiday weekend

Comment: I think it should be `2>&1` instead of `2&>1`. (SO wouldn't let me edit only 2 characters in the answer.)